# Weird message when I hit Send/recieve on Outlook on Mac

Tags: mac, mail.app, ms-office

Now this message has just had me confused for couple of days lately. I have an outlook on Mac and It does work fine for the most part(Sending and receiving the messages successfully without any problems).

However, there is a butting called Send/receive which I am used to pressing when I wan to update my inbox explicitly rather than relying on automatic updates. Now, when I do this, it pops with a message that looks like below:

[image]

I am not too sure how to get rid of this message. I am also failing to understand why does this message even exist since I clearly do have the correct credentials in the system. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have an email stuck in the Outbox.

Outlook is nowhere near the horror show it used to be but it is a complicated beast that wouldn't know an understandable error message if it bit it.

So look down the left hand side of your Outlook window in the folders. There is likely one there called Outbox and it is in bold possibly with a "(1)" next to it.

Open the outbox and the email in it and verify that the email address is correct and any attachments are not too big for your mail service and click on the send button.

Failing that you could copy the email into a *NEW* message and try sending it again.

If you are otherwise sending and receiving email then you are not in offline mode and it is most likely it is an email stuck in the Outbox.